# indexing in returning only few of the columns specified in query in data-import xml

Tags: solr

```
indexing in returning only few of the columns specified in query in data-import xml.
<entity 
          name="All_Manuals" 
           query="SELECT Query........"
          dataSource="JdbcDataSource">        
            <field column="Column1" name="id" />
            <field column="Column2" name="deptId" />
            <field column="Column3" name="groupId" />
            <field column="Column4" name="subGrpId" />
            <field column="Column5" name="manualId" />

        </entity>
```

We are indexing above all columns, but when we are fetching it is returning only first two columns.

Comment: check if you have mentioned other columns in schema.xml and stored=true is for them.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add all columns in your schema.xml like this :

```
<field name="id"      type="string"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  />
 <field name="deptId"      type="string"   indexed="true"  stored="true"  />
 <field name="groupId"      type="string"   indexed="true"  stored="true" />
  ..............................
```

and suppose if you dnt want indexing on any column but still want that cloumn in your results

```
<field name="xxxxx"      type="string"   indexed="false"  stored="true" />
```